# How to create Jquery FileUpload with ASP.NET C# included CRUD (not MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-file-upload

Hi I have saw a lot of documents on the google search and found many pages to discuss php / python (like [jQuery File Upload Demo](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)) etc.. However I didn't see anything about ASP.NET for C# or VB(not MVC),so anyone can help me to give me any slim clue, Hopefully give me full example code or reference URL that it is included CRUD, by the way I will be continuing search and try to deal with this issue

Ps: CRUD means  to create/read/update/delete

I have tried [this sample](https://github.com/jay3dec/FileUploadInAspxUsingjQuery) but I had get some error messages as following pictures

Console
[image]

NetWork
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my question and I've tried to fix my problem as following steps.
1. To modify url at the main.js

```
$(function () { 
    'use strict';
    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: 'server/******/'   // to your cs location
    });
```

2.To check all Css and JQuery that are address is okay to get script

Answer (score 3):

Let's establish a common understanding.

- CRUD = create read update delete
- jquery fileupload -> file upload

Not sure what kind of CRUD operation do you require from jquery fileupload. Can you elaborate further on your requirement?

If you want some reference on how to use the plugin, perhaps this [tutorial here - aspnet web form and jquery file upload](http://codehandbook.org/jquery-file-upload-asp-net-csharp/) will help.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi@Sudarpo thanks for your feedback and I've tried it(tutorial here - aspnet web form and jquery file upload) in my environment ,but unfortunately it isn't work, hopefully you can give me whole example code if you have ,thanks

Comment: Hi Willie.. There's a full solution in bottom page (under Wrapping up section). [github link](https://github.com/jay3dec/FileUploadInAspxUsingjQuery)

Comment: Can you take a look at NETWORK tab and see where it went wrong?

Comment: @WillieCheng, did you try to upload any file? your "network" only showed traffic from BrowserLink. and it's hard to tell what's the problem if you don't share the code.

Comment: I copied source code from website and I rat it in my VS ,I didn't touch or change anything, and then I got error messages like you saw. by the way ,could you do me a favor to copy the source code and run it in your environment , hopefully you can see the same questions thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138888/discussion-between-sudarpo-chong-and-willie-cheng).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for C# ASP.NET

**JS Function**

```
function SaveFiles() {

        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        var file = $("#fileInput").val();

        if (file.length > 0) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/Admin/UploadImage');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');

            //Appending file information in Http headers
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', fileInput.files[0].name);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type', fileInput.files[0].type);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size', fileInput.files[0].size);
            xhr.setRequestHeader['X-File-FileName', 1];
            xhr.setRequestHeader['X-File-Id', id];

            //Sending file in XMLHttpRequest
            xhr.send(fileInput.files[0]);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function (data) {

                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

                    alert("Image Uploaded Successfully...");

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**C# Code**

```
public JsonResult UploadImage()
        {
            string fileName = Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
            string fileType = Request.Headers["X-File-Type"];
            int fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Headers["X-File-Size"]);

            System.IO.Stream fileContent = Request.InputStream;
            System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImg/" + fileName));
            fileContent.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

            //Copying file's content to FileStream
            fileContent.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Dispose();

            string FileName = Server.MapPath("~/UploadImg/" + fileName);

            //Here you can code for insert in database

            return Json(FileName);
        }
```

Comment: Hi @RAJNIK thank for your help,but I need to use JQuery File Upload to do my project , so do you have any idea for my problem ,thanks again